# Not able to view dashboards after integrating LDAP in superset

Tags: ldap, apache-superset

With Authentication Type as DB, I was able to login with admin/admin. I had all the permissions.
Now I have changed my superset's config.py to use ldap server,
`AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP    AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = "ldap://...*"    AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=example,DC=com"  AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"    AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "**********"  AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = "sAMAccountName"`

After making these changes and installing pythonldap in my environment, I was able to successfully login.
But now, I dont have permission to view/create dashboards/charts or do any other thing
[Snapshot after logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFyHH.png)